# Slow Startup Of Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Whenever I want to open Firefox it takes a second or two before I even see the window. Chromium-based browsers like Chrome or Brave launch instantly. I don't have issues with any other app except for Firefox. Is there something I can do to make it start faster?

I also prefer Chrome's "where to save your file" options when I download something since Chrome opens an Elementary os UI, Firefox have something totally different in that regard. Is there  something similar in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

If the browser was installed via the AppCenter then by default you got a Flatpak version of Firefox. For most purposes Flatpak apps are fine, but for extremely large applications like Firefox it maybe useful to install it as a system-level program instead:

1. Go to the AppCenter and uninstall Firefox
2. Open Terminal and run this command:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to roll back to old version, I have similar issue after the update. It takes to long start up

Answer (score -1):

> Whenever I want to open Firefox it takes a second or two before I even
>   see the window. Chromium-based browsers like Chrome or Brave launch
>   instantly. I don't have issues with any other app except for Firefox.
>   Is there something I can do to make it start faster?

Get a SSD if you don't have one, disable extensions that you don't use, disable pocket if you don't use it. You can also disable disk cache and use only RAM cache if you have enough RAM, however this won't matter for startup probably.

To disable pocket you need to go to `about:config` and set `extensions.pocket.enabled` to `False`.

> I also prefer Chrome's "where to save your file" options when I
>   download something since Chrome opens an Elementary os UI, Firefox
>   have something totally different in that regard. Is there something
>   similar in Firefox?

If you go to Preferences > General > Files and Applications you can set it to "Always ask you where to save Files".